# Refresh some jquery on browser window resize

Tags: jquery, browser, resize, refresh

I am using a third party carousel which adds in-line widths and heights styles on the fly. The site uses media queries to resize the carousel container when the browser size is reduced. My issue is that the page has to be refreshed for the media query to come in. So can I have the jQuery function refresh on resize so it re-work out its widths/heights?

Here's the jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
    // include options like this:
    // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
    carouselSpeed:700,
    smallFeatureWidth:0.8, smallFeatureHeight:0.8, sidePadding:0, topPadding:0
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `resize()` function on the `window` object:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
        // include options like this:
        // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
        carouselSpeed:700,
        smallFeatureWidth:0.8, smallFeatureHeight:0.8, sidePadding:0, topPadding:0
    });
});
```

Then you can use `$(window).height()` and `$(window).width()` to get your new size and adjust from there.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough I was searching for refreshing on window re-size for the exact same reason. I have a logo scroller in a responsive design and the images are stacking on top of each other when the window re-sizes. The best solution for this is the following:
1-place the scroller in an iframe
2-add a class to the iframe with the logo scroller on the parent page and use java to refresh the iframe on window resize.